# When typing in a Datagridview's combobox select from sql

Tags: c#

When I'm typing something in my combox where value > 3(Characters) to start filling (my combobox) from SQL where name like my datagridview's combobox.

Example:

```
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name FROM Customers where name like '%" + Column1 + "'", con);

        SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (sqlReader.Read())
        {
            Column1.Items.Add(sqlReader["Name"].ToString());
        }

        sqlReader.Close();
```

But in which event should i place this code? And how can i set it when Combobox value >3 characters start running my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your code on `ComboBox` `OnSelectedItemChanged` event:

```
ComboBox1_SelectedItemChanged (EventArgs e)
{
      if (ComboBox1.SelectedItem.Length>3)
      {
          ///place your code here...
      }
}
```

Comment: My Combobox is a datagridview's Combobox. Example Column1